# How to get rid of the black console window for a compiled Haskell GUI application

Tags: user-interface, haskell, gtk, glade

I have compiled a Haskell GUI application with `stack-1.7.1`, `ghc-8.2.2`, `gtk+-2.24.28` and `glade-3.8`. When I run the executable, a black console window always follows the GUI window. I want to get rid of it, but I don't find any tips about Haskell GUI application. I'm still new to Haskell, especially to the Haskell compilation. So I'm sorry if this is an easy task, but I appreciate it if anybody could give me some tips.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your `.cabal` file:

```
if os(windows)
    ghc-options: -optl-mwindows
```

If you don't use `cabal` for building your project, simply pass `-optl-mwindows` to `ghc`.